# Seagate 4TB, 3,5" / SATA III (ST4000DM000) and SK-3500 Super-S Combo

Tags: imac, disk-utility, external-disk, disk-format

I bought a 4TB 3.5", SATA III Seagate Desktop HD and put it into a SK-3500 Super-S Combo. My iMac (late 2009) did, however, not detect the HD when I connect it. Since I cannot see it, I am unable to format it. The HD is also not shown in the Terminal after `df -h`. When I type `diskutil list`, however, I get the following from Terminal:

```
0:                                                   *4.1 GB     disk1
```

After `diskutil list` the HD is now shown in "Disc Utilities" but featured as "non-writeable" and I cannot create a partition or format it. Not sure why but I suspect that the problem could be the SK-3500 enclosure and I should try another enclosure.

If you have any ideas what else I could try (aside from trying another enclosure), I would appreciate any input very much.

Comment: Did you try resetting the SMC?

Comment: Yes I did as described here: [http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964]. Now it doesn't even show up after `diskutil list` in "Disc Utilities".

Comment: After trying `diskutil list`in the Terminal several times (and after approx 25 mins), the disk is shown again in the Terminal and also in Disk Utilities. In Disk Utilities the HDD's status is "read only" and the S.M.A.R.T status is "not supported". It is also featured as "unformatted". Partitioning is not available.

Comment: I have checked the enclosure with the manufacturer: it can only hold HDD with a capacity up to 2 TB. Since the capacity limitations were not posted on their website, it is always a good idea to double check the enclosure specs when you go beyond 2 TB.

Comment: If you post that as a answer we can close this as done .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datastore SK-3500 Super-S Combo enclosure only supports HDDs up to 2 TB. I will now either buy a Synology DS412+ or LMP DataTower 430.